# Optimization in sum of array in java

Tags: java, arrays, algorithm, optimization

I have an array and a long type variable called `total` that stands for it's sum.

If the array is of length n then the summation of it should be done like this:
`sum = arr[0] + arr[n-1] + arr[1] + arr[n-2] +...` until `sum >= total` and I have to print a string of the elements in the sum

My Approach : 
I have executed loop till `n/2` if n is even or `n/2 + 1` if n is odd.

I am doing something like this :

```
String s = "";
if (n % 2 ==0)
     loop = n/2;
else 
     loop = n/2 + 1;

for(int i=0 ; i < loop ; i++){
     sum += arr[i];
     s += arr[i] + " ";
     if(check(sum , total)==true) break; //this function checks if sum>=total.
     sum += arr[n];
     s += arr[n] + " ";
     if(check(sum , total)==true) break;
     n--;
}
System.out.println(s);
```

Example : arr[ ]={10 , 20 , 30, 40, 50} and total = 120 then output should be :

```
10 50 20 40
```

my approach stills gives TLE in some test cases. I need more optimized solution than this. Help me here.

Comment: what's TLE? And how is `check` breaking the looping? Is it throwing an exception?

Comment: TLE is time limit exceeded.

Comment: TLE is time limit exceeded and it is not throwing an exception.

Comment: `check` shoudl be within an `if`

Comment: please post your `check` function

Comment: There is no real reason to keep the string and concatenating it. Print as soon as you add.

Comment: Try `long sum = LongStream.of(arr).parallel().sum();`.

Comment: Have you tried looping sequentially – by that I mean summing elements as they are ordered in the array? Instead of taking the second element from the end of array, take the next element after the current one. Theoretical efficiency would be the same, but the approach that I am suggesting might have better utilization of cpu cache.

Comment: "If the array is of length n then the summation of it **should** be done like this: sum = arr[0] + arr[n-1] +". Question: **should or must**?. Because jumping back and forth on the array will cause quite a performance hit for very large arrays, **if it is not a MUST** then doing the summation in strictly increasing sequence of the index is better.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Why not to do that this way:

```
for (int i = 0; sum < total && i < loop; i++) {
    sum += array[i];
    System.out.print(String.valueOf(array[i]) + " ");
    if (sum < total) {
        sum+=array[n-1-i];
        System.out.print(String.valueOf(array[n-1-i]) + " ");
    }
}
```

Comment: Upvoted. Out of interest, do the online judges penalise `i++` over `++i`?

Comment: @Bathsheba why should they in Java on integers?

Comment: @Bathsheba, that would be extremism for sure.

Comment: These days I agree but are not these online judges a law unto themselves?

Answer (score 0):

you can organise your array first the do the tratement. something like this :

```
String s = "";
orgArray(arr);

for(int i=0 ; i < (arr.lenght)-1; i++){
     sum += arr[i];
     s += arr[i] + " ";
     check(sum , total);
}
System.out.println(s);
```

and the function will be some thing like this :

```
public static void orgArray(string tab[]) {
        int longueur = tab.length;
        int tampon = 0;
        boolean permut;

        do {

            permut = false;
            for (int i = 0; i < longueur - 1; i++) {

                if (i + 1 < longueur - 1 - i) {

                    tampon = tab[i + 1];
                    tab[i + 1] = tab[longueur - 1];
                    tab[longueur - 1] = tampon;
                    permut = true;
                }else {permut = false;}
            }
        } while (permut);
    }
```

hope that help you.